# Read in a directory from a given file point in C++

Tags: c++, file, directory

I have two programs that will be reading / writing files to the same directory at the same time (but not to the same exact files at the same time). I have the writing portion done, but I am struggling to get a half way decent and working implementation of the reading directory portion.

The files within the directory follow the following naming scheme:
`Image-[INDEX]-[KEY/DEL]--[TIMESTAMP]`

`[INDEX]` increments up from `000000`, `[KEY/DEL]` alternates based on whether the image is a key or a delta frame and `[TIMESTAMP]` is the Unix / Linux epoch time at file creation.

Right now, the reading program reads in the directory (using the `dirent.h` library) one file at a time every time it needs to find an image within the directory. When the directory gets extremely large, I would imagine that this operation / method will quickly become extremely resource intensive, and eventually fail. So, I am trying to find an alternative method. I was thinking of reading in the entire directory at initialization, and saving the file information in an array to access / use later in the program. Then, when a file is requested that is not in the array, the program would go and update the array of files by reading in the directory, but this time starting from the point it left off at the end of the initialization.

Is this possible? To start reading in the file names within a directory at a known point (the last file "read in") in the directory? Or do I have to start all the way from the beginning each time?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to " When the directory gets extremely large, I would imagine that this operation / method will quickly become extremely resource intensive"? I currently process 90k files in one directory in sub second time...

Comment: There's no guarantee new directory entries will be in the end, so this method will not work. You may however use `inotify` and `readdir` together (call `inotify_add_watch` before calling `opendir`).

Comment: @AndrewWhite I'd be curious to know if you've ever tried that on an NTFS volume.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the answer is no. I have only done this on the ext4 filesystem

Comment: @AndrewWhite I guess my only evidence is via graphical interfaces, which this will not be. What sort of sub second timing are you experiencing. This program will occasionally need to "read in" directories that size in under 200 ms.

Comment: @n.m. Is there still no guarantee that new files will be "appended" to the end of the directory, even if they are sequential / incremental?

Comment: No guarantee of any order whatsoever by `readdir`.

Comment: What operating system? Also, might files be inserted in the middle of the sequence, or can you discount that possibility?

Comment: @Ben This is all on a unix system. As for the file insertion, I am not 100% certain that sequentially named files would ONLY be added at the "end" of the directory. They never appear that way when I ls via the command line, but I have seen `readdir` return files and folder out of sequence. So, I have been exploring what @n.m. suggested.

Comment: @AeroBuffalo, I don't mean the "end" as returned by readdir, I mean the logical end as understood by your application, i.e. the end as in the order you want them. Since readdir doesn't provide a guarantee of the order files will be returned you should be checking this yourself anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew said, I would confirm that this is actually a problem before trying to solve it.

If you can discount the possibility of files being created out of sequence, that is, no file
 you wish to process before another file will ever be created after that file, then you can use this method.

First, read the entire directory listing into an array or `vector`. Then, when iterating files, just iterate the vector. Finally, if you get a file not found or reach the end of the vector, refresh it just in case more have been created.

You will no doubt want to encapsulate this logic into some sort of context object, which remembers the last file read. You could also optimise by sorting the vector.