# Obtaining only partial entryInfoList from Qt's QDir to avoid scanning the whole directory?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, tree, directory

A Qt C++ Windows application scans a directory structure from disk (on a network-connected *nix server) and "caches" the paths in a local file.

The directory structure is extended regularly with further subdirectories, which I would like to add to the now "stale" "cache" file efficiently by not reading known paths again.

Is there a way to "seek" (QDir or lower-level) to the last known subdirectory and start "scanning" from there?

From [Read in a directory from a given file point in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348532/read-in-a-directory-from-a-given-file-point-in-c) I gather the entries may not be in order so even if there were a way to start reading where last stopped, it may return known directories and miss the new ones.

So is there no alternative than always reading a whole directory?

Comment: I've also found http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html#details but "Unlike Qt's container iterators, QDirIterator is uni-directional (i.e., you cannot iterate directories in reverse order) and does not allow random access."